# Assembly Power(A,b) function

Tags: c, assembly, x86, nasm

I'm trying to make an assembly power(a, b) function, based on this c code:

```
int power(int x, int y)
{
    int z;

    z = 1;
    while (y > 0) {
        if ((y % 2) == 1) {
            y = y - 1;
            z = z * x;
        } else {
            y = y / 2;
            x = x * x;
        }
    }

    return z;
}
```

Though, for some reason, it only gets some outputs right, and I can't figure out where the problem is. Here is my assembly code:

```
;* int power(int x, int y);                                                  *
;*****************************************************************************
%define y [ebp+12]
%define x [ebp+8]
%define z [ebp-4]



 power:
push   ebp
mov    ebp,esp
sub    esp,16
mov    byte[ebp-4], 1
jmp    L3;

L1:
mov    eax,[ebp+12]
and    eax,0x1
test   eax,eax
je     L2;
sub    byte[ebp+12],1
mov    eax,[ebp-4]
imul   eax, [ebp+8]
mov    [ebp-4],eax
jmp    L3;

L2:
mov    eax,[ebp+12]
mov    edx,eax
shr    edx,31
 add    eax,edx
sar    eax,1
 mov    [ebp+12],eax
mov    eax,[ebp+8]
imul   eax,[ebp+8]
mov    [ebp+8],eax

L3:
cmp    byte[ebp+12],0
jg     L1;
mov    eax,[ebp-4]
leave  
ret
```

When I run it, this is my output:

```
power(2, 0) returned -1217218303 - incorrect, should return 1
power(2, 1) returned 2 - correct
power(2, 2) returned -575029244 - incorrect, should return 4
power(2, 3) returned 8 - correct
```

Could someone please help me figure out where I've gone wrong, or to correct my code, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Learn to use a debugger and comment your code especially if you want others to help.

Comment: Do you realise that `if ((y % 2) == 1)` is easier to code in assembler when rewritten as `if ((y & 1) != 0)`? No comparison is required, just a test and branch.

Comment: @WeatherVane Most compilers should be smart enough to replace division / modulus by a power of 2 by the appropriate shift / mask.

Comment: @dbush is an assembler that smart? I was suggesting it is easier to translate when written that way.

Comment: No, I haven't. The C code was given to me as is to code into assembly. It's not great, I know. @WeatherVane

Comment: @WeatherVane Strike that... was looking at the C code and assuming a compiler.

Comment: I can see what the decrement is doing now.  It causes the next iteration of the loop to go to the `else` portion, so the divide / square is delayed until the next iteration.  Seems like a kludge though, as it means an extra evaluation of the conditional for each set bit.

Comment: @dbush nice, I was wondering why my compilation of the C code gave always correct answers in this unusual implementation.

Comment: @WeatherVane I made the changes that you suggested, still having the same problem.

Comment: You changed it to `and eax,0x1; test eax,eax` but it should be just `test eax,1` and also you might add some code comments as per first remark from Jester, for example I have no idea why you are doing 31-bit shifts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're storing a single byte, then reading back that byte + 3 garbage bytes.

```
%define z [ebp-4]    ; what's the point of this define if you write it out explicitly instead of  mov eax, z?
                     ; should just be a comment if you don't want use it

mov    byte[ebp-4], 1     ; leaves [ebp-3..ebp-1] unmodified
...
mov    eax, [ebp-4]       ; loads 4 bytes, including whatever garbage was there
```

Using a debugger would have shown you that you were getting garbage in EAX at this point.  You could fix it by using `movzx   eax, byte [ebp-4]`, or by storing 4B in the first place.

Or, better, don't use any extra stack memory at all, since you can use ECX without even saving/restoring it in the usual 32-bit calling conventions.  Keep your data in registers, that's what they're for.

---

Your "solution" of using `[ebp+16]` is writing to stack space owned by the caller.  You're just getting lucky that it happens to have the upper 3 bytes zeroed, I guess, and that clobbering it doesn't lead to a crash.

---

```
and    eax,1
test   eax,eax
```

is redundant: `test eax, 1` is sufficient.  (Or if you want to destroy eax, `and eax, 1` sets flags based on the result).

There's a huge amount of other inefficiency in your code, too.

Comment: Thanks for the input.